# path lists java 6 in java_home, but why does cmd use java 7 for java while javac uses java 6?

Tags: java

I have both java 6 and 7 installed for compatibility reasons.  Right now, I need to use java 6 but I don't want to uninstall java 7.  I looked carefully at the path and replaced java 7 with the path to java6 in java_home.  closed and restarted another cmd window.  Java 7 is 64 bit and java 6 is 32 bit.

Currently,

javac gives 1.6  which is what I expect, however, I'm not sure why java -version gives 1.7.  How do I make it so that on windows 7 command prompt, when I type java - version, it would give java 6 instead?

i renamed the java 7 folder, and when I type java, I get this error:

C:>java
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'

I thought the path would dictate what version of java will be used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rename the folder -- it simply will corrupt the existing installation. Instead make sure that in the `PATH` environment variable, a reference to `%JAVA_HOME%` exists *before* any path that contains Java. Typically a Java launcher exists in the Windows directory (e.g. the `C:/Windows/system32` folder), which may still be using a different version than the one used by `JAVA_HOME`. Try to have `%JAVA_HOME%` referenced before that path in the `PATH` variable:

```
PATH = %JAVA_HOME%;other_paths
```

Comment: IT WORKS! =)  Thank you, thank you!  By chance, do you know if %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem has a say in determining the java variable?  I removed that from the path but that wasn't enough to solve the issue until I put java_Home first.  Thanks again, Manouti. =)

Comment: I don't know about that path but try not to remove anything since it may cause other executables not to be found. In all cases, the solution here was to place `JAVA_HOME` first in order to override any other path that contains the Java executables.